# Big Nerd Ranch Android. RecyclerView won't display data

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview

Kind of a shot in the dark here. Maybe somebody will have an idea what I'm talking about but I'm stuck on a problem that I've tried everything on to no avail :(

It's chapter 9 at the very end in the second edition of the Big Nerd Ranch Android book, 2nd Edition. When I run the code on the simulator all I get is a blank white screen with a tiny blue bar at the top, I'm supposed to have custom list items in a listview.

I have the code exact at this point but my recycler view won't show any data from the model. To make this easier on the eye rather than copying and pasting a bunch of places here is the repository for where I can't get it. I've toyed around with XML files and my logcat doesn't give me anything noteworthy. I'm using Android Studio 1.5

repo: https://github.com/Hart87/Criminal-Intent

Comment: Please do show the code. Specifically, a [mcve]

Comment: I took a small glance at your git repo, and i think you are not inflating your list fragment in your CrimeListActivity

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've inflated a blank Fragment. Perhaps you meant `new CrimeListFragment()`?

```
public class CrimeListActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected Fragment createFragment() {
        return new Fragment();
    }
}
```

And make sure you've `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` in `CrimeListFragment` and all your other classes that use it.

Comment: That was a good step in the right direction by you both but once I edited the code you mentioned I had an error pop up in another class. "SingleFragmentActivity" at the line "fragment = CreateFragment();"  The error said "CrimeListFragment could not be converted to Fragment"

Comment: It compiled and ran but no listView displayed. Is there anywhere special I should be looking? Im not new to mobile dev just new to android

Comment: The List of data or the adapter could be empty. Or you have not set the width/height of the RecyclerView in the XML correctly and the view is hidden